# Determinar cuantas vocales tiene una cadena en java

Tags: java, string, consola

Implemente mediante la clase String, una aplicación que cuente el número de vocales de un texto.
El algoritmo que he diseñado es el siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando trato de codificar el algoritmo, todo va bien hasta que trato de comprar con la propiedad ".charAt" el caracter con "a"... Ya que me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Existe una forma más óptima?** o **¿Cómo puedo corregir mi error para poder seguir codificando mi algoritmo de forma correcta?**

**Por favor recordar que esto es programación secuencial**

Comment: Por favor, pon la información como texto, no como capturas de pantalla. Además, el algoritmo es irrelevante para solucionar un error de sintaxis (el problema es cómo invocas el método, no porqué invocas el método).

Comment: Por respeto a las normas comunitarias:  ¿Debo editar la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, tu error de compilación se debe a que estás trantando de comparar dos tipos distintos. La función `charAt(x)` devuelve un char, representado normalmente como `'a'`, con comillas simples. Cuando lo intentas comparar lo haces contra un String al usar las dobles comillas `"a"`. Lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiarlas para que funcione.

Con respecto a la eficiencia, lo único que te diría es que en lugar de hacer muchos if anidados uses la estructura switch-case, que visualmente es mejor y hace las comprobaciones por detrás de la forma más eficiente y rápida.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como haría yo esa parte:

```
String cadena = "Esto es una cadena para contar las vocales";
int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < cadena.length(); x++) {
    char actual = cadena.toLowerCase().charAt(x);

    switch (actual) {
        case 'a':
            a++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            e++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            i++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            o++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            u++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Total de vocales: " + (a+e+i+o+u));

System.out.println("Cantidad de a: " + a);
System.out.println("Cantidad de e: " + e);
System.out.println("Cantidad de i: " + i);
System.out.println("Cantidad de o: " + o);
System.out.println("Cantidad de u: " + u);
```

EDITADO:
He añadido una conversión a minúscula para que compruebe todas las vocales independientemente de como estén escritas

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas en las que puedes contar todas las vocales de una cadena. Pero primeramente habría que determinar qué tipo de vocales podría tener el texto. Por ejemplo, si debería manejar vocales acentuadas o no, y qué tipos de acentos, en castellano, en francés, en polaco... Según eso, tendrías que incluir en la evaluación la posibilidad para esas vocales.

Aquí te muestro varias formas posibles de hacerlo para un conteo general de vocales.

Si también quieres contar cada vocal por separado, ver parte II de la respuesta.

<kbd>[**VER DEMO COMPLETO EN REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/JYM4240)</kbd>

## I. Conteo de vocales en general

### Forma 1: con expresiones regulares

Esta sentencia encontrará todas las vocales castellanas, mayúscula o minúsculas, dentro de una cadena:

```
int totalVocales = s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiouÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]","").length();
```

La ponemos en un método, y la probamos:

#### Método `contarVocales`:

```
public static int contarVocales(String s){
    int totalVocales = s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiouÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]","").length();
    return totalVocales;
}
```

#### Prueba:

```
    String helloWorld="Hello world áéíóÚ";
    totalVocales=contarVocales(helloWorld);
    System.out.println(totalVocales);
```

**Output:**

```
8
```

---

### Forma 2: Con un ciclo `for`

Aquí no he incluido las posibles vocales en castellano (acentuadas), pero se podrían incluir.

```
public static int contarVocalesFor(String s){
    int totalVocales = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      if ((c == 'A') || (c == 'a') || (c == 'E') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'I') || (c == 'i')
      || (c == 'O') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'U') || (c == 'u'))
        totalVocales++;
    }
    return totalVocales;
}
```

#### Prueba:

```
String loremIpsum=
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."+ 
    "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. "+
    "Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "+
    "Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."; 

totalVocales=contarVocalesFor(loremIpsum);
System.out.println(totalVocales);
```

**Output:**

```
162
```

---

## II. Conteo general y parcial

Vamos a adaptar el método para que nos devuelva un `HashMap` con cuántas vocales hay de cada una y un conteo general.

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> contarVocalesMap(String s){
      HashMap<String,Integer> mapTotal=new HashMap<String,Integer>();  

    int totalVocales = s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiouÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]","").length();
    int totalA = s.replaceAll("[^AaÁá]","").length();
    int totalE = s.replaceAll("[^EeÉé]","").length();
    int totalI = s.replaceAll("[^IiÍí]","").length();
    int totalO = s.replaceAll("[^OoÓó]","").length();
    int totalU = s.replaceAll("[^UuÚú]","").length();
    mapTotal.put("a",totalA);
    mapTotal.put("e",totalE);
    mapTotal.put("i",totalI);
    mapTotal.put("o",totalO);
    mapTotal.put("u",totalU);
    mapTotal.put("all",totalVocales);
    return mapTotal;
}
```

Probamos el método:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> mapTotalVocales=contarVocalesMap(loremIpsum);
    System.out.println(mapTotalVocales);
```

**Output:**

Tendrás un mapa como este, con la información general y por vocales, sería cuestión de leerlo:

```
{all=162, a=28, e=38, u=29, i=42, o=25}
```

**NOTAS:**

1. Los métodos pueden todavía mejorarse, haciéndolos por ejemplo *nullsafe*.
2. Podríamos pensar incluso en una `Clase` con un alcance mucho más amplio, que tuviera varios métodos como: `getTotal()` para todas las vocales, `getOne()` para una vocal dada, `getOpen()` para obtener sólo las vocales abiertas... Obtener sólo las vocales en mayúscula, con acentos, sin acentos... y todo lo que querramos con las vocales. :)